# How do I install matplotlib whl files to Python on Windows 7?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to install Matplotlib into a Python installation. But I can not install it because there aren't any EXE files; rather there are whl files. I don't know the way of installation of whl files.

Comment: where did you find the .whl file for Windows 7? Could you post a link ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install using:

```
pip install matplotlib*.whl
```

Or alternatively, [Matplotlib does have executables](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/downloads).

Comment: Thank you very much..i got the answer